# is my Wordpress insecure?

Tags: wordpress, xss

i've been doing some research on how XSS works and realized my Wordpress site its vulnerable to script through the comments section.

I've done a very silly test who i belived it would not work at all. Posted the following comment:

```
    Hello Wold!"> <script> console.log("owned!") </script>
```

And for my surprise it was submitted and the console logged:

```
    > owned!
```

I don't know much about this kind of vulnerabilities but I think this i**s not normal behaivor**. Anyone can post a comment with a malicious script and take control of my site.

Can someone please give some advice on this?

Answer (score 0):

1) You Need add captcha on the form and check the comment from admin if there is any script remove it.
2) Install wordreference wp plugins and block the unwanted IP address and loctions
3) Change default user and password